# SpringBootの@ControllerAdviceの挙動について

Tags: java, spring

現在SpringBootを使用していて、エラーハンドリングをControllerAdviceで行っています。
また、filter(javax.servlet.Filter)を使用してControllerに入る前にライブラリの読み込みなどを行っています。

今回、このfilterの部分でRuntimeExceptionがキャッチされるとControllerAdviceがエラーハンドリングしてしまいクライアントに意図しないエラーレスポンスが返ってしまう挙動を発見しました。　(filter内のExceptionのキャッチはエラーログを出すだけで、スローやreturnなどは行いません。　つまり処理は継続されます。)
私の理解ではControllerAdviceはController層に入った後で起きたエラーについてハンドリングされる認識で、filter内でのException(しかもスローしていない)のエラーがハンドリングされてしまうのが不可解です。

この現象が、私の実装に原因があるのか、それともSpring側やfilterなどの仕様の理解不足かなど分かりますか？

以下に実装を簡単にしたものを示します。

@Controller

```
public void  control() throws MyException {
   log.debug(“start”);   <- ここまではきていない
 :
 :
}
```

@MyException

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDEN, reason=“test my exception”)
Public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    :
}
```

@ContollerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAdvice {

  @ExceptionHandler({MyException.class})
  public Object handleMyException(Exception e, WebRequest r) {
       :      
  return HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN          <- (このメソッドがハンドリングします)
  }
}
```

@filter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain fc) throws IOException {
      :
     try {
          Object obj = ライブラリの読み込み. ← （今回これがRuntimeExceptionを投げてきます)
           :
      } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage);
     }
}
```

※filter内で以下のようにエラーが起きる部分をtry節から抜くとControllerAdviceがハンドリングしないことがわかっています。

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain fc) throws IOException {
     Object obj = ライブラリでの処理. ← （今回これがRuntimeExceptionを投げてきます)
     Try {
           :
      } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage);
     }
}
```

Comment: 質問内容だけを見ると、フィルタの後続の処理でも別の例外が発生しており、その例外が`ControllerAdvice`に捕捉されているだけのように見えます。stack traceで例外の出どころは確認されていますか？(`handleMyException` の引数をログ出力などすれば確認できるかと思います)

Comment: すみません、勘違いしてましてfilter層を抜けた後に@componentがついたクラスが処理をしており、このクラスがMyExceptionをスローしておりました。なので今回の問題自体はここのハンドリングか、filterでのハンドリングをしっかりやれば良さそうです(RuntimeExceptionそのまま投げてくるので考える必要はありそうですが..)。　お騒がせいたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今回の問題は結局サーブレットの中身までリクエストが届いており、そこでスローされていたのである意味期待通りでした。
filter内でExceptionを補足しない場合、@ContorollerAdviceがハンドリングしないのも、結局フレームワーク側などで捕捉が漏れたExceptionをキャッチして再スローしている(そのためControllerには届いてないのでハンドリングされない)のだと考えています。